# In react how to detect the button id clicked on not

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In this case when I clicked the button I want to access the button Id and also want to checked that button is clicked or not. here I have use the `e.currentTarget.id`to detect the button ID and want to checked that its clicked or not by using `document.getElementById("yourID").clicked === true`. But after clicking the button its not give the alert. So how do I achieved that

```
import * as React from "react";
export default function Map() {
  const getButtonId = (e) => {
    if (e.currentTarget.id === "yourID") {
      if (document.getElementById("yourID").clicked === true) {
        alert("button clicked");
      }
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button id="yourID" onClick={getButtonId}>
        Button
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: onClick is triggered when a button is clicked. Why are you checking if it is clicked inside the same function?

Comment: yes basically I want to trigger the Id of the button when its clicked so initially if i give e.currentTarget.in it gives the initial id but I want when button was clicked

Comment: Please explain the use case. Are you trying to check if the button has been clicked 2 times?

Comment: basically I want the id after clicking the button not before clicking the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there is no need to use `document.getElementById("yourID").clicked === true` because `button` has `onClick` property that you are using which does what you want.

And as to solve your problem, you have a `typo` in your code. You typed `yourId` in `e.currentTarget.id === "yourID"` instead of `yourID`

```
const getButtonId = (e) => {
    if (e.currentTarget.id === "yourID") {
        alert("button clicked");
   }
}
```

Comment: ya still its not working

Comment: I tried it in sandbox it works.

Comment: Did you remove `if (document.getElementById("yourID").clicked === true)` from your code?

Comment: yes at that time its working but my question is how to detect the particular id when button is clicked ,but initially i did not want to detect the id

Comment: You are already checking it here `if (e.currentTarget.id === "yourID")` the code won't run further if `button id` isn't equal to `yourID` so why do you need to doublecheck?

Comment: ya basically i have to check in formik errors that if button is clicked then there should be no errors so i want to detect the button thats i want to apply in my formik conditions

Comment: but there is no need for it because `onClick` will only run if someone would `click` on it.

Comment: ok thanks for giving the support